# Can't match programs to Bash's total from double tab press

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

In `Bash`, if I press the tab key twice, then I see:

> Display all **1092** possibilities? (y or n)

Snippet:

```
!         diff              ifconfig      mount.fuse        rcsdiff       tiff2pdf
./        diff3             ifdown        mount.ntfs-3g     rcsmerge      tiff2ps
:         diffutils-cmp     ifenslave     mount.ntfs-fuse   rdisc         tiff2rgba
GET       diffutils-diff    iftop         mountpoint        rdjpgcom      tiffcmp
HEAD      diffutils-diff3   ifup          msgattrib         read          tiffcp
MAKEDEV   diffutils-sdiff   ifup-local    msgcat            readelf       tiffdiff
POST      dig               igawk         msgcmp            readlink      tiffdither
[         dir               igd-client    msgcomm           readonly      tiffdump
--More--
```

I thought that if I searched for all the executable files in the directories in my `$PATH` environment variable, then that would produce a single column list matching the data that `more` displays.

Here's my first attempt:

```
echo $PATH | sed -e 's/:/ /g' -e "s/^/find / " | sh > commandlist.txt
wc -l commandlist.txt
1114 commandlist.txt
```

So I added `-xtype f` and `-perm /u=x` but still don't get 1092:

```
echo $PATH | sed -e 's/:/ /g' -e "s/^/find / " -e "s/$/ -xtype f -perm \/u=x/" | sh | wc -l
1107
```

How does `double tab key press` in Bash generate its total 'possibilities' value?

Comment: I would guess that *aliases* and shell *builtins* (like `cd` or `ulimit`) are also counted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
compgen -cab | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

on my machine it shows the same number as the tab complete thing.